# How can I add options to `make` command?

Tags: command-line, make, clang

I am trying to add options to the `make` command. For example to add -l option to include libraries. Something like `clang filename.c -o filename` to `clang filename.c -o filename -l{libary}`

What should I do and what file should I edit?

Comment: Does the project you are trying to build actually have a makefile? or are you typing the `clang` command you showed manually?

Comment: typing `make` runs `clang filename.c -o filename` i just want to add options to it so that it runs for example `clang filename.c -o filename -l`

Comment: OK but does that command come from an actual Makefile in the current directory, or because you have set the default `CC` to `clang`?

Comment: yeah i changed the default `CC` to `clang`

Comment: @Satori have you considered using makefiles with `make`→ https://www.gnu.org/s/make/manual/html_node/Simple-Makefile.html

Comment: You still haven't told us if the project has a Makefile or not.

Comment: no. sorry i forgot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `export LDLIBS='-l'` in my .bashrc file.

Answer (score 4):

Since you don't have a Makefile, compilation and linking of your program relies on implicit rules built in to `make`. In the case of C source code, the implicit rule for **Linking a single object file** is:

```
$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)
```

So you can add libraries via the `LDLIBS` variable e.g.

```
make LDLIBS='-lfoo'
```

or

```
LDLIBS='-lfoo' make
```

See [GNU make: 10.2 Catalogue of Built-In Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules)

Comment: where do i put these?

Comment: @Satori you can add them to the `make` command line - exactly as I wrote. Or if you're too lazy to type them, make an alias `alias make='make "LDLIBS=-lm"'` but I don't recommend it - once you start modifying build commands, it's better to create a minimal Makefile for your program.

Answer (score 1):

According to fedorqui, an alias cannot accept a parameter. Hence, you must create a function in `~/.bashrc`.

```
acp ()
{
clang "$1".c -o "$1" -l
}
```

Execute with

```
acp "filename"
```

It's said that it is important to use double quotes to avoid just getting the first parameter, i.e. if there's a space in the filename.

*Note that I did not test this.*

Reference: [User Input to Bash Alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359049/user-input-to-bash-alias)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, the simplest thing would be to make an alias in your .bashrc or .zshrc or whatever shell you are using.

I would not recommend you to edit something somewhere else.

But you could look where you find the program, some programs are scripts, written in perl for example, and can be edited to your will

Comment: how should i alias it because the filename is going to be different each time?

Comment: You can work with parameters of this helps. I don't really see the bigger picture of your situation, pls elaborate

Comment: I'm just trying to include a library when i compile the code, but the `make` command doesn't have the `-l` command and runs `clang filename.c -o filename` so i want to include the `-l` in the make command so every time i use it runs `clang filename.c -o filename -l`